# Given an array of arrays, how can I replace all empty values with 0?

Tags: php, arrays, null

Example array

```
$myArray[0] = array('23', null, '43', '12');
$myArray[1] = array(null, null, '53', '19');
$myArray[2] = array('12', '13', '14', null);
```

All nulls should be replaced with 0. I was hoping someone would have an efficient way of doing this, perhaps a built in PHP function that I am unaware of.

Comment: You know that the subarrays have only one element, namely a string?

Comment: There is no 'efficient' way of doing this - there's just one way, which is to traverse through all values in the array. It doesn't get any better than O(n) for this. Also, you made a typo in your code - get rid of those single quotes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the [**`array_walk_recursive`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function, with a callback function that would replace `null` by `0`.

For example, considering your array is declared this way :

```
$myArray[0] = array(23, null, 43, 12);
$myArray[1] = array(null, null, 53, 19);
$myArray[2] = array(12, 13, 14, null);
```

*Note : I supposed you made a typo, and your arrays are not containing only a string, but several sub-elements.*

You could use this kind of code :

```
array_walk_recursive($myArray, 'replacer');
var_dump($myArray);
```

With the following callback functon :

```
function replacer(& $item, $key) {
    if ($item === null) {
        $item = 0;
    }
}
```

Note that :

- the first parameter is passed by reference !

  - which means modifying it will modify the corresponding value in your array
- I'm using the `===` operator for the comparison

And you'd get the following output :

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => int 23
      1 => int 0
      2 => int 43
      3 => int 12
  1 => 
    array
      0 => int 0
      1 => int 0
      2 => int 53
      3 => int 19
  2 => 
    array
      0 => int 12
      1 => int 13
      2 => int 14
      3 => int 0
```

Comment: @Felix : no, `$item` should not be an array : I'm using the **recursive** function ;-) which means the callback is called for the sub-elements *(integers)*, and not the elements *(arrays)* themselves.

Comment: I noticed it seconds after my comments that is why i deleted my comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

If the single quotation marks are unintentional, and the arrays have integers and null values:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++)
{
    if ($myArray[$i] == null) $myArray[$i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From PHP7.4 and higher, you can use arrow function syntax to make iterated calls of `intval()` on each row.  This is safe to use on your data because none of the input values will be damaged by unconditionally casting them to `int` type data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/R8XTs))

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn($row) => array_map('intval', $row), $myArray)
);
```