# Iphone application crash when i post JSON data through PHP webservice having null values

Tags: php, ios, multidimensional-array, crash

I am developing webservice through PHP for Iphone Application that convert send JSON object to Iphone App whenever webservice called.

Problem is while converting the  deep multidimensional array that may contain some null values.I want to covert all all the null values into empty string so that my application don't get crash.Is there any way to check deep inside the multidimensional array sometime its too deep for removing all null values.and one more thing is i need solution in such a way that it don't slow down the whole process because its the mobile application and if there is any solution i can tell to my mobile developer that they can handle it from their side

**Example of the array is provided**

```
Array
(
    [result] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [basic_detail] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Coca-Cola Company
                    [industry_detail] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [industry_name] => Beverages
                                )

                        )

                    [category_detail] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_name] => Soft drinks
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_name] => Water
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_name] => Juices
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_name] => Energy & Sport Drinks
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_name] => Hot Beverages
                                )

                        )

                    [Nationality] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => American
                        )

                )
            [Story_text] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: try http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php function in php

Comment: i am already using json_encode before sending data to iphone application but still they are getting null values
ex:$json_result = json_encode($result); \

Comment: array_walk_recursive will help refer to answer for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647959/given-an-array-of-arrays-how-can-i-replace-all-empty-values-with-0

Comment: thanks @LalithB for the solution thats what iw as looking for  it worked  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add `null` value to your array, use

```
[array addObject:[NSNull null]];
```

It's value is equal to `null` and your application won't crash if your array contains some `[NSNull null]` objects.